# Rails : How to invalidate an action cache that takes parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, parameters, action

I have an action in my Rails controller that accepts some parameters that are used for filtering and pagination. The response returned is only in JSON format and there is no view template.

I understand that caching can be done for the action and parameters using caches_action and cache_path. What I do not understand and have not been able to find is how to invalidate the cache for that action across all parameters. The cached action is similar to an "index" action and if there is a create/update/delete, the pagination is affected so the entire cache for that action must be removed.

This must be a fairly common problem, but I haven't been able to identify how it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think of and from googling is to create custom cache keys for the cache_path attribute:

- If looking up a single item, the custom cache key includes the updated_at date for that item.
- If looking up a list of items, the custom cache key includes the count of items and the last updated_at date for the list of items.

The negative side-effect is that there will be database calls even if there is a cache hit.
The positive side-effect is that the cache is self-expiring since I am using memcached and memcached uses LRU replacement.

I get the feeling I am re-inventing the wheel but I cannot find solid documentation anywhere to solve this problem better.